# A problem occurred starting process 'command '\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe''

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After spending two days still not figured out what's happening.

I'm getting below error while building the App after merging the code.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting
>   process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\jre\bin\java.exe''

This is happening in a specific git branch. the same project runs successfully from another branch.

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled v3.1.3
2. Also updated to latest Android Studio v3.3.2

Still getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Also add following dependency :

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: already enabled. as said in the question, It's working in other git branches of the project